# Thermal Printer autocuts the Uncomplete recipt leaving last two lines

Tags: java, netbeans, thermal-printer, pos

I am trying to print a receipt using java in net-beans IDE. The problem that I am actually facing is:

1. With the help of software provided by the printer manufacturers, when I press cut command, printer performs auto cut perfectly leaving no line behind.
2. Using java code for auto cutting the receipt, it leaves last two lines unprinted onto the receipt while auto cutting.

The problem is may be with my java code. Especially with this line may be, `byte[] cutP = new byte[] {0x1d, 'V', 1 };`

I would really appreciate for your help.

```
public class printer {
    public void printString(String printerName, String text) {

    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);
        PrintService service = findPrintService(printerName, printService);
        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

        try {

            byte[] bytes;

            // important for umlaut chars
            bytes = text.getBytes("CP437");

            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
            job.print(doc, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

try {
    printer printerService = new printer();
    printerService.printString("POS-588", "                 CFC CAFE\n                   (Near Railway Station,Vehari)\n     Contact# 0300-0810999     0336-3810999\n    *******************************************\n  Items            Quantity             Price\n\n");
    // cut that paper!
    byte[] cutP = new byte[] {0x1d, 'V', 1 };
    printerService.printBytes("POS-588", cutP);
}
```

Comment: The solution to this problem was very simple... I just needed to put some more \n in the end of the recipt to have some blank space at footer. However thanks a lot.

Comment: Formatted code to improve readability